# Creating Zip file using shutil module in python

Tags: python, shutil

This code will create a plots.zip file, but the problem is that it creates another plots.zip inside that zip file.

`shutil.make_archive(outPath + "plots", 'zip', outPath[:-1])`

I have tried this method but it is not working:

`shutil.make_archive(outPath + "plots", 'zip', outPath[:-1])`

It generates like this

```
folder
│   script.py
└───subfolder1
│   │   file011.txt
│   │   file012.txt
│   │
└───subfolder2
│   │   file011.txt
│   │   file012.txt
│   │
└───zipfile_name.zip
│   │   same content as above (as expected)
│   │   zipfile_name.zip
```

Comment: `outPath` seems to be a string, so `outPath[:-1]` is the whole string except the last character is omitted (maybe a whitespace?). The `shutil.make_archive(base_name, format[, root_dir])` uses the `root_dir` as third parameter. If the root dir is a zip file, the zip file will be generated in a zip file. Try to use `os.path.dirname(outPath)` instead...

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example of your code. Without it, we are only guessing.